# Unexpected Border spacing in html table

Tags: html, css, user-interface, html-table

I am able to see border between cells in a table refer the images below, you will be able to see the background color. I am observing this behavior on mobiles devices such as Ipad and Andriod tab

[image: Table over the yellow background]

[image: Same table over the blue background]

save the above page as index.html and if you are using chrome then 
 1. Open the debug tools
 2. List item
 3. Click on the toggle device toolbar
 4. Choose the IPAD and play with zoom level you will be able to see the difference

```
<html>
<head>
    sdfsdf
</head>
<body  style="background: #c5c3c8;">
    <style>
        #root-GA-1-GA-1 .objbox table tbody tr.odd_material td {
        background: #3b3f45 ;
        color : #ffffff;
        }
        #root-GA-1-GA-1 .objbox table tbody tr.ev_material td {
        background: #2e3135 ;
        color : #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="root-GA-1-GA-1" style="width: 980px; height: 1271px; cursor: default;">
        <div class="objbox" >
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="obj" style="width: 980px; table-layout: fixed;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class=" ev_material" style="height: 50px;">
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0 ">K1</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0 ">AA</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class=" odd_material" style="height: 50px;">
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0 ">K2</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0 ">AB</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class=" ev_material" style="height: 50px;">
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0   ">K3</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0   ">AC</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class=" odd_material" style="height: 50px;">
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0 ">K23</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0 ">AaC</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class=" ev_material" style="height: 50px;">
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0  ">K334</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="cell_style0  ">ACa</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any idea on how to get rid of these weird lines?

Comment: can you add your complete code? So i can check it

Comment: i am trying create a fiddle for it

Comment: @NileshNaik I have updated my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should really provide HTML code along with the CSS, this helps determine if there is something wrong in the HTML.

But if you are using `<table>` tag, you should also add `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"`

So your `<table>` tag should look like this:

`<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`

EDIT:

Also worth mentioning CSS resets as different browsers and devices render ever so slightly differently.  The below resets for `<table>` and it's children should work, then you can remove the `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` from the `<table>` tag.

```
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;       
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Hi @ScottieG I have updated the table code. Also I am able to observe this on mobile devices

Comment: no it was already there. I am observing this issue in tablets. its working fine in chrome and laptops

Comment: Can you provide the full CSS and supporting HTML so I can take a look?

Comment: @PragamShrivastava I have modified my original answer, this should help.  Let me know how you get on.

Comment: I observed that theres some anomaly in the width of table

Comment: my screen size is 1024 and the table width is coming to 1023.2, I am assuming that its related to the space that I am seeing between cells. with your current fix the spaces are adjusting themself. it has not fully solved the issue

Comment: Set the `body { margin: 0; }`